# how to present UITabBarController that used UINavigationController from ViewController ouside

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

i have UiViewController as a LoginPage if it passed then it should show UITabBarController firstTab's ; the first tab inside UINavigationController as RootView.

how can i present firstTab from Login Page; i tried the following but error show :

## Code IOS 7 StoryBoard

```
-(void)successLogin{
    HomeTableViewController *vc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootViewInControllerInFirstTabBar"];
    [self presentViewController: vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that the view that should appear after the login page should have tabs- with the first tab selected. the frst tab should have the home tableVC, which is also the root controller of a navigation controller, displayed.

***[Updated]***

According to my understanding of the doc, you'll first create the login page.
On successful login, the screen will navigate to a new controller derived from UITabbarViewController. Navigation to the UITabbarViewController depends on your choice, or you can even replace the view on the login screen(entirely your choice). Now on the derivedViewController you will set the viewcontrollers that you want to display on each tab using the following method of the UITabbarViewController.

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

On the first item of the tab bar, you will create a new controller(for profile) which will be the rootviewController of the UINavigationController.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your reply will i can view any Tab not only the first  Tab from Login but i can't view the rootView which is under UINavigationController that under first Tab in UITabBarController. this is my problem :((

Comment: please check this document it contains what i need [Document Link Click Here](http://www.mallpt.com/login.pdf)

Comment: @user3353382 what is the issue that you are facing now?